# Need Some Pointing to Portion of code in John The Ripper

Tags: c, algorithm, brute-force

i don't like this kind of tool myself, but ppl say its the fastest in cracking passwords in brute force, but my interest isn't cracking passwords, i need the algorithm that generates the brute force data, like "AA, AB, AC,......ZA", but i cant seem to find it in the source, can anybody just tell me what will it look like or where should i look for it in the source?

or if anybody knows a good and fast algorithm to generate these strings according to a given charset?
like

```
  char *charset1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  char *charset1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  char *charset1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ........
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break your problem down.

1. Generate all one character strings A - Z
2. Generate all 2 character strings AA - ZZ
3. Generate all 3 character strings AAA - ZZZ
4. etc.

Now consider treating, e.g. AAA - ZZZ, as a problem in printing all possible 3-digit numbers in base 26 (or however many characters there are in your character set)

John the Ripper starts by using a different technique, with its built in dictionary:

> password
>   Password
>   passw0rd
>   Passw0rd
>   etc.

ETA: Here is some sample code for the two character version, AA - ZZ.  My C is extremely rusty, so this fragment is Java:

```
// Character set
String charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int cSetSize = charset.length();

// Two character strings AA - ZZ
int numChars = 2;
int limit = cSetSize * cSetSize;
char[] result = new char[numChars];

// Build strings
for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {

    // Convert i to base cSetSize
    int current = i;
    for (int j = numChars - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
        result[j] = charset.charAt(current % cSetSize);
        current /= cSetSize;
    }

    // Do something with string
    System.out.println(new String(result));
}
```

Comment: but aside with the Dictionary tech. it uses bruteforce too, i think. and im just asking to find the fastest algorithm, i wrote my own, but it contains lots of if statements and loops, so i was asking if i can find the fastest to read it and maybe make it even faster

Comment: @killercode: Set up a for-loop.  Convert the index to a base-n number where n = 26, 36, 52, 62 or whatever.

Comment: u have a sample or something?

Comment: i found this lib in c (http://sourceforge.net/projects/crunch-wordlist/) but its extremely difficult for me to understand, can u help me taking out the code to start generating from specific location? like start at "aad" and continue from there? thanks

Comment: @killercode: If it is difficult for you to understand the SourceForge code then you are probably better off writing something simpler for yourself.  Start by doing the problem on paper and convert your paper method into your own code.

Comment: im sure its a simple method used in that code, im just confused with all the other code around and mathematics that i never seen before